# Sequelize JSON data type

Tags: mysql, json, node.js, sequelize.js

I have defined a model as

```
module.exports = function (sequelize, DataTypes) {
  const MyModel = sequelize.define('MyModel', {
    data: {
      type: DataTypes.JSON,
      ...
    },
    ...
  });

  return MyModel;
};
```

I query it using

```
MyModel.findAll().then(myModels => ...);
```

However, `data` field in the query result is a string, not a JSON object. How do I fix it?

Comment: Use ``JSON.parse(data)``

Comment: @AkshayKumar That is not what I suppose should be required. If the field type is already JSON, it should return JSON and not a string.

Comment: @MikkoP which database are you using?

Comment: @divsingh MySQL is in the tags, so I'd guess MySQL

Comment: Works as expected in postgres.

Comment: It works as expected now, with MySQL version 8.0.23 and Sequelize version 6.6.2. No need to define setters and getters.

Answer (score 34):

It's not supported yet [MySQL JSON Data Type #4727](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/4727). But you can do something like this:

```js
module.exports = function (sequelize, DataTypes) {
    const MyModel = sequelize.define('MyModel', {
        data: {
            type: DataTypes.TEXT,
            get: function () {
                return JSON.parse(this.getDataValue('value'));
            },
            set: function (value) {
                this.setDataValue('value', JSON.stringify(value));
            },
            ...
        },
        ...
    });

    return MyModel;
};
```

I also found this package on github [sequelize-json](https://github.com/Growmies/sequelize-json) you can give it a try if you don't want to use getters and setters.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, this works so perfectly Thank you Jalal, Also the sequelize-json module is unneeded, it also hasn't been supported in 3-4years, and this works for everything. 
One thing to note is that this.getDataValue('value'), value should be 'data', or whatever your field name is.

Comment: apparently JSON support was added to sequelize in version 4.18 https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/pull/7106#issuecomment-339549850

Comment: Keep in mind that MySQL will truncate values to the column's max length with no error which means the stored JSON could be broken (triggering a parse error). The `set()` function should validate the length before saving.

Answer (score 23):

No need to use getters and setters as JSON is now supported by sequelize.See [sequelize api](https://sequelize.org/master/manual/other-data-types.html#json--sqlite--mysql--mariadb-and-postgresql-only-)

Comment: To the top with you!

Comment: That's not very clear. You link to the documentation of `DataTypes.JSON` which OP is already using.

Comment: nice heere is a link to what he is saying https://sequelize.org/docs/v6/other-topics/other-data-types/#json-sqlite-mysql-mariadb-and-postgresql-only

Comment: I added the data type JSON and I still get a string.... I had to use the getter

Answer (score 10):

Jalal's answer was great but didn't work for me unless I tweaked it a little. Here's what worked for me:

**First:** create a migration that adds the field you want as type `TEXT`.
example - I want to add a field called `address` to the `Stores` table:

```
module.exports = {
  up: (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    return queryInterface.addColumn("Stores", "address", Sequelize.TEXT);
  },

  down: (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    return queryInterface.removeColumn("Stores", "address");
  }
};
```

**Next:** 
Inside your model, add the field with getters and setters to your list (object) of fields and datatypes:

```
address: {
  type: DataTypes.TEXT,
    get: function() {
      return JSON.parse(this.getDataValue("address"));
    },
    set: function(value) {
      return this.setDataValue("address", JSON.stringify(value));
    }
},
```

So my entire model looks like this:

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const Store = sequelize.define(
    "Store",
    {
      name: DataTypes.STRING,
      isActive: DataTypes.BOOLEAN,
      address: {
        type: DataTypes.TEXT,
        get: function() {
          return JSON.parse(this.getDataValue("address"));
        },
        set: function(value) {
          return this.setDataValue("address", JSON.stringify(value));
        }
      }
    },
    {}
  );
  Store.associate = function(models) {
    // associations can be defined here
    Store.hasMany(models.Order, {
      foreignKey: "id",
      targetKey: "storeId"
    });
  };
  return Store;
};
```

**Now** you can create and retrieve records just like you would with a JSON type field in the db.

For example: `const store = await Store.create({name: "Joe's corner store", address: {address1: "123 test street", city: "Los Angeles", state: "CA"}})`

Some notes:

In the above code blocks...

- Replace `address` with the field name you want to use.
- Replace `Stores` with your model/table name.
- I added `return` on the setter, otherwise it was erroring out when trying to create a new record (the way Jalal has it).

Answer (score 3):

While this question is tagged MySQL, I suspect some people using MariaDB might end up here anyway, especially since MariaDB is now the default in many places.  There's a difference in how the JSON data type is treated between MySQL and MariaDB, which is why sequelize implements it differently for these two DBs.

In my case I fixed this issue by explicitly switching sequelize to dialect `mariadb`.  This requires you to install the `mariadb` package instead of `mysql2`.  Afterwards my JSON columns were correctly parsed to an object.

Comment: Exactly what happened to me

Answer (score 2):

JSON data types aren't supported for MySQL.

See the docs here http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/v3/docs/models-definition/#data-types

A work around could be to use text and stringify/parse when querying it

Comment: JSON for MySQL is supported as of Sequelize 4.18

Answer (score 2):

The easiest solution is to use this little library called [sequelize-json](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sequelize-json)

Create a database and a Schema:

```js
var Sequelize = require('sequelize'),
  JsonField = require('sequelize-json'),
  db,
  User;

db = new Sequelize('database', 'username', 'password', {
  dialect: 'sqlite',
  logging: false
});

User = db.define('User', {
  username: Sequelize.STRING,
  jsonField: JsonField(db, 'User', 'jsonField')
});
```

Note the parameters of JsonField, you pass your Sequelize instance, the name of the model, and the name of the field. A little awkard, but this is needed in order to add the proper hooks to the model instance.

Now, you can always treat that field as a json object:

```js
User.create({
      username: 'Scott',
      jsonField: {
        likes: ['running', 'node']
      }
    })
    .then(function(user) {
      user.jsonField.likes.push('tests');
      return user.save();
    })
    .then(function(user) {
      expect(user.jsonField).to.be.a('object');
      expect(user.jsonField.likes).to.have.length(3);
    });
```

It will work with normal save commands, as well as updateAttribute commands.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you ! I made further changes with the provided code above,

```
myColData:{
      type:DataTypes.TEXT,
      get:function(){
        return JSON.parse(this.getDataValue("myColData"));
      },
      set:function(value){
        return this.setDataValue("myColData", value);
      }
    }
```

I think it works fine if we don't stringify the data in the setter function
If you stringify in the setter you might have to parse it again when you actully fetch the data.

Answer (score -1):

in sequelize v6, no need to use JSON.parse() since it returns Object itself.

Comment: it doesn't in my case