# Query JSON Data using SequelizeJS on MS SQL Server 2016

Tags: json, sql-server, sequelize.js, sql-server-2016

I'm working on a project that requires querying JSON data via Sequelize.

I want Sequelize to query something like this (without raw queries):

```
SELECT doc 
FROM Families f 
WHERE JSON_VALUE(f.doc, '$.id') = N'AndersenFamily'
```

The Query above retrieves id key from json-data residing in the doc column where the `id = 'AndersenFamily'`.

Is this possible to achieve in sequelize? or is there a workaround?
Thank you!

Comment: Have a look at this question to see if it helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41280608/sequelize-json-data-type

Comment: @digital.aaron I've already tried using getters and setters but was looking for a better solution